# rvm requirements install git error

Tags: ruby, git, rvm

I'm trying to install `rvm` with latest ruby on a centos 5 server, rvm is already installed with no ruby, it throws an error when trying to install ruby, something regarding git.

```
$ uname -a
Linux 2.6.18-308.24.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Dec 4 18:28:32 EST 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ rvm install ruby-2.2-head
Checking requirements for centos.
Installing requirements for centos.
Installing required packages: git, autoconf.......
Error running 'requirements_centos_libs_install git autoconf',
showing last 15 lines of /home/ruby/.rvm/log/1442954643_ruby-2.2-head/package_install_git_autoconf.log
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
++ return 1
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.


$ git --version
git version 1.6.4.4
```

This hosts uses cpanel.

I've tried directly installing with yum, same error, tried also to remove git

```
 # yum remove git
 Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
 Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror
 Setting up Remove Process
 No Match for argument: git
```

My guess is that Cpanel has git installed, but is an outdated version, could be this?

Comment: I've found this post on cpanel forum than discourage installing git on server https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/installing-git.294411/

Answer (score 0):

Try the answers provided here -- https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2696 --  specifically fixing whatever goes wrong when you try to do this...

`yum install -y libyaml-devel autoconf gcc-c++ readline-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel`